# Laravel response quote mark '

Tags: laravel

I move the app to other server and all responses come with a quote mark `. How i can remove that.
I reviewed php.ini, nginx. If install a new clean project of laravel not happen.

Comment: put your `layout file` or else do `ctrl+U` and put a screenshot here.

Comment: You should post both your code as well as your response, so that we can understand your problem better.

Comment: double check all involved blade templates and middleware to make sure this isn't coming from an accidentally placed character somewhere

Comment: The can sometimes be caused by a comma being placed before the opening php tag of a file.

Comment: Really no was nothing related to our code. I did something so simple like create a route and put a return there with an empty variable and in the web showed  ` 
So after of several fail test we decide reinstall server and everything.